# topic remapping in synchronised message_filters

Tags: ros, message-filters, remapping, image-transport, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to synchronise a compressed depth image and its camera info:

```
image_transport::SubscriberFilter sub_image(it, "image", 10);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> sub_info(n, "camera_info", 10);
message_filters::Synchronizer<ApproxSync> sync(ApproxSync(100), sub_info, sub_image);
```

The original topics are:

- `/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth`
  (to be mapped to: `image`)
- `/camera/depth/camera_info` (to be mapped to: `camera_info`)

Only the compressed depth has been logged.

I am using the arguments
`image:=/camera/depth/image_rect_raw _image_transport:=compressedDepth camera_info:=/camera/depth/camera_info` for the executable, which are supposed to remap the topics and select the image transport.

However, rqt's Node Graph shows that the node is subscribing to `/image/compressedDepth`, i.e. it is ignoring the topic remapping for `image` but applies the image transport extension of the topic before the remapping.

The synchronisation works, when using the full topic names and only the argument `_image_transport:=compressedDepth`:

```
image_transport::SubscriberFilter sub_image(it, "/camera/depth/image_rect_raw", 10);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> sub_info(n, "/camera/depth/camera_info", 10);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290472/topic-remapping-in-synchronised-message_filters/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2018-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A workaround is to manually remap the topic via `ros::names::remap(<topic>)`:

```
image_transport::SubscriberFilter sub_image(it, ros::names::remap("image"), 10);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> sub_info(n, ros::names::remap("camera_info"), 10);
```

---

Originally posted by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) with karma: 214 on 2018-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No remapping lookup is done on the base_topic for image transport plugins before the transport type is appended: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/f9e705aac2218f0ba97fd029e9d7ba709d17dae4/image_transport/include/image_transport/simple_subscriber_plugin.h#L98-L101 (I'm not sure if this lookup is done elsewhere or not).

If you think this is a bug, you should report is on the image_transport bug tracker: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on 2018-05-06**:
Thanks for pointing to the relevant parts. There is already a bug report at: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues/80